# change Frequency of coming data

Tags: sockets, filtering, frequency, gyroscope

I Have a Sensor (Gyro) that connected to my python program (with socket UDP) and send data to python console in real-time but with 200 Hz frequency.

I want to change this frequency of coming data to my console but could not find a good way to do it.

I was thinking about doing it with filters like Mean an waiting for idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have *regular updates*, use a windowing mechanism. Take the last *n* values and store the average. Then, discard the next two values and take the last *n* values again. This example would yield values with a frequency of 200 Hz/2.

If you only want to see events when changes have occured, store the last value, compare the current value with the last one and emit an event if it has changed, updating the stored value. As you're dealing with sensors (and thus, a little fuzziness), you probably want to implement a [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis).

You can even raise the frequency by creating extra values in between the received ones through interpolation. For a steady frequency, you would have to take care about your timing though.